# Where do Forgotten Beasts spawn?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to wall off the edges of the first cavern layer to prevent Forgotten Beasts from spawning there. I've observed that after I built a wall around the first set of walls that creatures starting spawning *on top of* the walls. So do Forgotten Beasts spawn at any of the following places on the edge of caverns:

- On top of dwarf-made structures
- On top of surface of water
- Underwater
- Open Space, for flying Forgotten Beasts

Comment: If you walled off the edge -1 square to leave space for the Beasts to spawn "legally", you might avoid this problem. Have you tried that?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Good idea, but it won't do for flying Beasts, and if they can spawn underwater / in mid-air then this won't do much good

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to *prevent* FBs from spawning.  Basically, what I recommend is to think of, and treat, the caverns *exactly* like you think of the surface: as fundamentally an area *outside* your fortress that you need to manage your fortress's interface with in order to achieve security.

Then it proceeds naturally that the measures that you employ to be secure with dragons arriving on the surface are the same measures employed to be secure with flying FBs arriving in the caverns.

Comment: Though it may bear mentioning that Dragons in DF can't fly. Rocs, however...

Answer (score 3):

Walling off the ground-level edge isn't enough - you need to wall off the *entire* open spaces on the map, which usually includes a few spaces of 'open air'.

Given that this is impossible to do via the map edge constructions currently available (statues / bridges), you might be better off walling in your dwarves, rather than the entire cavern itself.

Map-edges touched by water are fair game for most forgotten beasts.